# .net core 8: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ubuntu, ubuntu-23.10

I'm trying to apply a migration
`dotnet ef database update`
But I only see a message:

```
Failed to load /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.so, error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.so)
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.so failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
```

command `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` returns me:

```
LIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.31
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

So, I've already installed `GLIBCXX_3.4.29`
Also, I tried different update|upgrade|build-essential installations options, but useless.
Could you help me?

Comment: You might want to run the strings command on `/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` instead? That's the libstdc++ that `dotnet` appears to be using.

Comment: Thanks, Omajid! Now, I've: ```strings /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Comment: That looks like the required glibcxx version is indeed missing. What I don't quite understand is why the dotnet at  `/usr/lib/dotnet/` (not a snap) is using `libstdc++` from `/snap/core20/current` (a snap location?). How are you calling this `dotnet` executable? Can you reproduce on a fresh machine or in a container?

Comment: Sorry, I cant reproduce on docker|fresh machine just now. What about a next part of your response, this is an output for /usr//lib/dotnet `/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet ef 
Failed to load /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.so, error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.so)
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /usr/lib/dotnet/host/fxr/8.0.2/libhostfxr.so failed
`

Comment: So, `sudo snap refresh ` and `dotnet tool update dotnet-ef --global` accomplished the deal! Thanks for assistance!

Answer (score 0):

So, `sudo snap refresh`  (update to core22) and `dotnet tool update dotnet-ef --global` accomplished the deal! Omajid, thanks for assistance!